# How to test a method which uses `instanceof ` on a mocked dependency

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a typeguard which checks the instance of a dependency.

```
  private isObjectOfA(obj: A | B ): obj is A {
    return obj instanceof A;
  }
```

In the spec file, I have mocked the class A.

```
jest.mock('./my-package/a', () => {
  return {
    A: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        someMethod: jest.fn()
      };
    })
  };
});

import { A } from './my-package/a';
```

Now during testing, `isObjectOfA` always returns false ( because in tests the instance of `obj` is returned as 'Object' instead of 'A'. Maybe due to the mock ??). Is there anyway to overcome this issue?
The code for the object creation looks like,

```
this.myObj = someCondition ? new A() : new B();
```

Comment: why would you pass a mock to this function?

Comment: @felixmosh, the class `A` is really complex in itself and has separate test cases. I do not want to test anything regarding `A` just to isolate my unit test cases here

Comment: As I understand, you won't test Class A but other method which uses it...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In order to pass `instanceof` check, prototype chain needs to be established, e.g. with `Object.create`:

```
jest.mock('./my-package/a', () => {
  const ActualA = jest.requireActual('./my-package/a');

  return {
    A: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      const a = Object.create(ActualA.prototype);
      return Object.assign(a, { someMethod: jest.fn() });
    })
  };
});
```

[Class auto-mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#automatic-mock) will provide correct prototype chain for a mock as well.

Comment: Thanks. `Object.create(ActualA.prototype)` made my day.

Comment: Made my day too! saved me bunch of hours.

Answer (score 1):

As I didn't want to rely on anything but the mock, my solution based on [@estus-flask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63462924)'s is as follows:

```
jest.mock('./module-to-mock', () => {
    const mockClass: jest.MockedClass<any> = jest.fn((...args) => {
        const instance = Object.create(mockClass.prototype);

        return Object.assign(instance, { args });
    })

    return {
        MyClass: mockClass
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> The instanceof operator tests whether the prototype property of a constructor appears anywhere in the prototype chain of an object.

This means that you can change the prototype of your mock to be `A`.

Answer (score 0):

If the complex implementation of the mocked class does not matter, which it shouldn't during the unit test phase then you can use ts-ignore. This will allow the TypeScript compiler to override the implementation and not have to worry about mocking complex dependencies.

This is how I did it and it worked for my purpose for one of my aws-cdk app.

Main Code

```
Aspects.of(this.cdkStack).add(new MyGlobalDenyAspect());
```

Mocking

```
const mockCdkStackImpl = { class: 'aws-cdk-lib/Stack', isMocked: true };
const mockAdd = jest.fn();
/*Notice Aspects.of returns an instance of the Aspects, but the 
following code replaces it to return a custom function that matches the 
expected implementation*/
const aspectsOfMock = jest
  .spyOn(Aspects, 'of')
  // @ts-ignore
  .mockImplementation(() => ({ add: mockAdd }));
```

Tests

```
it('should call aws cdk Aspects.of with cdk stack', () => {
expect(aspectsOfMock).toHaveBeenCalled(mockCdkStackImpl);
});

it('should call aws cdk Aspects.add with LmGlobalDenyAspect type', () 
=> {        
expect(mockAdd).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(MyGlobalDenyAspect));
});
```